# Is this the correct implementation of the BEM naming convention for navigation?

Tags: css, bem

I am trying to implement a main menu (including sub menu) for a website using the BEM CSS naming convention. I have found myself nesting elements which I think is an antipattern of the convention?

```
<ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Main item</a>
        <div class="nav__submenu">
            <div class="nav__group">
                <h3>Nav group</h3>
                <ul class="nav__group__list">
                    <li class="nav__group__item">
                        <a class="nav__group__link" href="#">Nav item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always though to nest deep. You can **not** have Element of Element in the BEM methodology. So this `nav__group__list` is not correct, could be `nav__group-list` for example.

The correct BEM markup could look something like this.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Main item</a>
        <div class="nav__submenu">
            <div class="nav__group">
                <h3>Nav group</h3>
                <ul class="nav__group-list">
                    <li class="nav__group-item">
                        <a class="nav__group-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However you can separate the "Group list", especially if it can be reused elsewhere in your project.
Your menu with separated `links-group` Block would look something like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Main item</a>
        <div class="nav__submenu">
            <div class="links-group">
                <h3 class="links-group__heading">Nav group</h3>
                <ul class="links-group__list">
                    <li class="links-group__item">
                        <a class="links-group__link" href="#">Nav item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been there and I know what you're trying to do - avoid styling by nesting for every price. Believe me it's not the way. Try to keep it simple, don't be afraid of making elements intended to be nested inside the other but don't use second-level nesting in your naming to avoid "really__long__class__names" and renaming everything in case you want to change the HTML structure. Think of BEM as a method of isolating components, breaking a complex UI into simple chunks easy to understand and maintain. In you specific case I'd probably go with something like this:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">Main item</a>

            <div class="nav--submenu">
                <div class="nav__group">
                    <h3 class="nav__header">Nav group</h3>

                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a class="nav__link" href="#">Nav item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Than I'd add a different styling for elements nested inside .nav--submenu. What you do want to avoid is cross-nesting between blocks, but inside them go with whatever feels right and if the block is getting too complex, think of extracting it's part to a new one.